# Servlet and Command pattern, compile vs runtime?

Tags: java, servlets, runtime, compile-time

I'm writing a Java servlet that acts as a Front Controller. To carry out functions I'm using the Domain Command pattern. Currently, I'm initializing all my commands and storing them in a map with the name (string) of the command as the key and the object as the value. Whenever the servlet receives a request, I get the command from the map by passing the command query from url as:

```
// at init
Hashmap<String, DomainCommand> commands = new Hashmap<String, DomainCommand>();
commands.put("someCommand", new SomeCommand());

// at request
String command = request.getParameter("command");
DomainCommand c = commands.get(command);
c.execute();
```

This works well and does what I want since my DomainCommands have no class attributes to be shared between threads. An alternative to this is using reflection to create the object like so:

```
String command = request.getParameter("command");
DomainCommand c = Class.forName(command).newInstance(); // assuming in same (default) package
c.execute();
```

Both of these work. Which is better from a performance/memory saving point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Performance

When using `Map` the only cost is accessing a `HashMap` (negligible). Reflection on the other hand might take much more time and is less safe - remember you have to make sure the user is not passing bogus `command`, allowing him to run arbitrary code.

## Memory

When creating `DomainCommand` at startup they will end up in old generation after some time, thus not being subject to garbage collection for most of the time. On the other when created per request most likely they will be garbage collected immediately. So in overall, the memory footprint will be comparable, except that the second approach requires mor GC runs.

All in all, map of commands is a much better approach. BTW if you DI frameworks like Spring or Guice (unless this is an overkill for you) or web frameworks like Struts/Spring MVC, they will do precisely the same work for you.

Comment: It's a school project, so I have to implement most of the functionality myself, but thanks this answers my questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach of storing the commands in `HashMap` is better. The problem with the second approach is that you have to load the command class every-time you execute that command.

In fact frameworks like Struts which precisely on command pattern with Controller Servlet as front controller with individual action classes as commands.

Answer (score 1):

From performance perspective the 1st approach you mentioned is definitely faster.

How about the following options?

1. using [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern for command
2. storing your command beans and do a lookup for command bean by its name (from the request) in JNDI (have a service that retrieves the command from JNDI)
3. using IoC framework (Spring) where all the command beans are initialized from the container startup and lookup for command is done on the application context

Performance-wise I would prefer the 3rd option.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an answer specifically from a performance/memory saving point of view, and the other answers answer that. I agree that the Map approach is probably better in this regard.

However, you should be sure that this is even a concern before worrying about that at this point; I'm assuming the network overhead to one call to your servlet by far outweighs a single HashMap lookup of a short string.

A larger concern should be clarity and maintainability. In this regard as well, I would say that the Map approach is much superior, as it:

- Doesn't tie the API (legal values of the command parameter) to the implementation (names of classes)
- Makes it clear which classes are intended to be used as commands and which are not (very important if you later want to make a change)
- Allows the API to be more flexible (for example, you could allow the command parameter to be case-insensitive, or to have more than one command map to the same class)

To quote the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit".

Answer (score 0):

How about merging the 2 options together?

Struts does the exact same thing. It contains a `Map` that caches all your commands that has been requested by the Servlet. If the command doesn't exist, then it creates a `newInstance()` of the command (just like option 2 you've created).

The advantage of this is quicker execution of your process: Retrieve the command from the cache else create a new one & and store the created new command in cache. It's definitely faster than option 2.